# Installing a WindowsService for debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, windows-services, onstart

I am trying to start my debug build `WindowsService` but am getting the error that it didn't start in a timely fashion.

I've cleaned up the ctor and `OnStart` but still it won't start so I am thinking maybe the dll it loads needs to be better installed, rather than just in the debug directory of my project directory. Maybe all that bumpf in `main()` is hanging it out to dry?

Any pointers for debugging the service? I can't run it directly in the VStudio because obviously that doesn't permit entry to its `OnCustomCommand(int cmd)` member and breaks it there.

Comment: For a windows service to start correctly the OnStart method needs to return within 30 seconds, so if you break anywhere in that method, or code that it calls you will get the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to debug the service before it's sitting in it's idle "Started" state?

You can use [Debugger.Break()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) function for this. For example, we often put the following into our Main function while in a debug build:

```
#if DEBUG

if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}

#endif
```

Comment: Currently I've compiled in Release mode as I felt my `#if _DEBUG MyService::startInstance(service); /*Put a breakpoint on the following line to always catch your service when it has finished its work*/ Thread::Sleep(Timeout::Infinite);` may have been responsible for the breaking. It works but won't break to VStudio. That is an interesting method you link to, thank you.

Comment: I can't get it to attach, more information would be useful- that's ok though, some good tips have come in under the Related section.

Comment: I think Debugger.IsAttached will be false, unless you start the service and attach to process quickly, *before* the code gets to the 'if' statement

Comment: Oh sorry, that was C# code by the way... That code is intended as a manual way to ensure that Visual Studio is prompted to maybe attach an instance for debugging. As Matt says, it's intended to only popup if debugger is not already attached - and his link shows some good ways to run the service fully interactive from a debugging perspective.

Comment: I think Debugger.Launch doesn't prompt to attach, Debugger.Break does

Comment: @Matt Oh yes! Right you are! Edited with your correction. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, C# vs C++ was obvious but trivial. I found to get it to attach I had to use "Attach to &Process" from the IDE. I couldn't do this from my main IDE instance when it was debugging something else so I opened another instance and now each thread gets its own single stepping- until I start firing messages between them and it gets harder to follow again.

Answer (score 1):

I would only do as little as possible in the OnStart method, enough init to kick off a thread that does all the work, so you can return from OnStart as quickly as you can. Then in the thread delegate you can add Reddog's code to break into the debugger, possibly with a thread.sleep in there so that it gives you time to attach to the process first.

Another alternative is to add a main method to your service, which can create an instance of the service class and call onstart/onstop, and change the project output to console app, then you get the best of both worlds, it'll install as a service via installutil, and you can f5 run it and debug it in visual studio as a console app.

Details [here](http://einaregilsson.com/2007/08/15/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/)

If you want to debug the service only as a service, then I would suggest that your OnStart method starts a thread that does the processing and then returns, the thread delegate then can do a Thread.Sleep(some reasonable amount of time) and then Debugger.Break();

The thread sleep gives you a chance to attach the debugger to the process, after you have started the service using service control manager, then it gets to the Debugger.Break() which will force the debugger to break, allowing you to single step. The key thing is to return from OnStart before 30 seconds, and to attach the debugger to the process before you hit your breakpoints.

Also, I think Debugger.Break gives you the option to attach the debugger, so try that in the code (not sure if it plays nicely with services though as they are supposed to have no UI) you might get away with sticking Debugger.Break into your delegate and attaching to the process before 30 secs.

Comment: The only downside to this approach is that it is not running as a true service able to handle `OnCustomCommand`. Reddog's code doesn't work, in my delegate or anywhere... Possibly due to VCExpress or my configurations.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't by default call OnCustomCommand, however you could modify the main method to accept input from the console and call OnCustomCommand yourself.

Comment: Oops, just noticed that OnCustomCommand is protected... however, you could expose a method on your service class that calls that method, to allow you to call it from a test harness. Personally the services I have written use the service base derived class as a thin wrapper around another class that can be instantiated and called from the service, or from a console app, so that testing can be performed.